# How Webview play the video of Html5 automatically

Tags: android, webview

When  I open the webview, I want the webview play the video of Html5 automatically,how to realize？

Comment: you have to enable auto play on the HTML side, not in webview.

Comment: thanks,I have got the answer       webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);                 String videoJs = "javascript: var v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]; v.play();";
wv_html.loadUrl(videoJs);

Comment: that won't work for all types of video playback.